How to display my list values ​in my DualListControl?
I have an ID and a label in my lstServices but my DualListControl is empty.
Everything worked a few years ago, do you have any idea why it doesn't work anymore ?
Dim lstServices As New ArrayList
Dim service As ServiceInfo

Dim lstServicesSelectionnees As New ArrayList
Dim serviceSelectionne As ServiceInfo
Dim lstServiceSelectionneEntite As EntityCollection(Of AssServicesEntity) = Data.ServicesController.getServices(currentFormulaire.IdFormulaire)
For Each myService As AssServicesEntity In lstServiceSelectionneEntite
    serviceSelectionne = New ServiceInfo
    serviceSelectionne.IdService = myService.IdService
    Dim tradService As AssTraductionLibelleEntity = Data.TraductionController.GetTraduction(myService.IdLibelle.Value, myVariante.IdVariante)
    If Not tradService Is Nothing Then
        serviceSelectionne.Libelle = tradService.Traduction
    End If

    lstServicesSelectionnees.Add(serviceSelectionne)
Next

For Each myService As AssServicesEntity In Data.ServicesController.getServicesByPortal(Me.PortalId)
    service = New ServiceInfo
    service.IdService = myService.IdService
    Dim tradService As AssTraductionLibelleEntity = Data.TraductionController.GetTraduction(myService.IdLibelle.Value, myVariante.IdVariante)
    If Not tradService Is Nothing Then
        service.Libelle = tradService.Traduction
    End If
    If lstServiceSelectionneEntite.FindMatches(AssServicesFields.IdService = myService.IdService).Count = 0 Then
        lstServices.Add(service)
    End If
Next

CType(dlServices, DotNetNuke.UI.UserControls.DualListControl).DataTextField = "Libelle"
CType(dlServices, DotNetNuke.UI.UserControls.DualListControl).DataValueField = "IdService"
CType(dlServices, DotNetNuke.UI.UserControls.DualListControl).Available = lstServices
CType(dlServices, DotNetNuke.UI.UserControls.DualListControl).Assigned = lstServicesSelectionnees

I tried to look at how the DNN controller is made but didn't find any problem.
This code is supposed to display a list of services in each block :
https://i.sstatic.net/9a2mN2KN.png
